# Как перезаписать файл в python

Tags: python

У меня есть парсер который создаёт файл .yml
Мне надо что бы фал постоянно перезаписывался не удалая его.

Вот так происходит создание файла

```
with open(save_path_file, "w",encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(xml_str)
```

Что мне исправить что бы файл перезаписывался, или он и так будет перезаписываться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр 'w' создает или перезаписывает файл. Вам ничего менять не надо